# smarty variable inside php

Tags: php, smarty

I need call smarty variable inside my php tag. I added function also .. 
this is my smarty variable

```
{get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}
```

//resut = google

My Function

```
function smarty_get_video_meta($params, &$smarty)
{
global $video; 
if (empty($params['uniq_id']) && empty($params['video_id']))
    return '';
$video_id = 0;
if ($video['source_id'] == 0)
{
    $sql = "SELECT item_id 
        FROM pm_embed_code, pm_meta
        WHERE pm_embed_code.uniq_id = '". $video['uniq_id'] ."'
        AND pm_embed_code.id = pm_meta.item_id";
        if ($result = mysql_query($sql))
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
            mysql_free_result($result);
            $video_id = $row['item_id'];
        }
}
else
{
    $video_id = $params['video_id'];
}
if ( ! $video_id)
    return '';
$meta = get_meta($video_id, IS_VIDEO, $params['key']);
return $meta[$params['key']];
}
```

php code

```
    {php}
    $url = $this->get_video_meta('test'); 
    echo $url; 
    {/php}
```

Comment: What's your problem / error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
{assign var="video_meta" value=$video_data}

{php}
$metas = $this->get_template_vars('video_meta');
echo $metas['id'];
{/php}
```

[get_template_vars](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/api.get.template.vars.tpl)
[assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)

**EDIT**:

The actual problem was: calling a function written for smarty templating between `{php}{/php}` tags... Which doenst really makes sense to me but still...

`smarty_get_video_meta(
   array(
      'video_id' => $video_data.id,
      'key' => 'Google'
   ), $this
 );`

This is how you would call the function in template files in PHP.

In smarty:

`{get_video_meta video_id=$video_data.id key='test'}`

Comment: it just echo video id, how can i use key?

Comment: Why not to assign whole array and access keys in php? Check edited answer

Comment: how to use video_id=$video_data.id??

Comment: Please be more specific

Comment: Pls check i added function

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what are you trying to do and how the function has anything to do with your main question **"How to use smarty variable inside php tags?"**

Comment: What u answered is every where in google .. i added my smarty code.. it use compare and use key .. thats what we have problem..

Comment: Let us continue [in this chatroom please](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106675/discussion-between-ksno-and-suresh)